# Android: Request GPS Provider for specific amount of time

Tags: android, service, gps

I am making a tracker app using GPS, in which it will collect user's current location and send it to the server. This whole process will run in background at an interval of every 15 minutes. I have been able to get it working. Now, the actual issue is I want to make request to GPS for a particular amount of attempts, say, for 5 attempts. If in that period it does not provides user's location, then I would like to switch to `NETWORK PROVIDER` for approximate location of user. I had used timer for location requests. But, I am unable to switch to `NETWORK PROVIDER` if GPS signal is unavailable after a specific no.of attempts. Below, I am posting my code:

```
public class MyLocationService extends Service implements
    OnLocationReceivedListener {

private LocationManager manager;
private Location location = null;
PowerManager powerManager;
private WakeLock wakeLock;
private String city, time, udid;
private String country;
MyLocationListener myLocationListener;
private static final int MAX_ATTEMPTS = 5;
private static String TAG = "MyLocationService";
LocTimerTask mTimerTask;
int mSattelites;
Timer myLocTimer;
int i = 0;
boolean isGPS;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.v(TAG, "onStartCommand called");
    getCurrentLocation();
    time = getCurrentTime();
    udid = getDeviceId();
    return 1;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.v(TAG, "onCreate called");
    powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
            "mywakelock");
    myLocationListener = new MyLocationListener();
    wakeLock.acquire();
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

public String getCurrentTime() {
    String currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
            Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());

    return currentTime;
}

public String getDeviceId() {
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) MyLocationService.this
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    return tm.getDeviceId();
}

public void getCurrentLocation() {
    manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    manager.addGpsStatusListener(mGPSStatusListener);
    mTimerTask = new LocTimerTask(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    if (manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        Log.v(TAG, "GPS ENABLED");
        manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000L, 50.0f,
                myLocationListener);
    } else {
        turnGPSOn();
        manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000L, 50.0f,
                myLocationListener);
    }

    myLocTimer = new Timer("LocationRunner", true);
    myLocTimer.schedule(mTimerTask, 0, 13000);
}

public String getLong(Location loc) {
    String longi = null;
    if (loc != null) {
        longi = Double.toString(loc.getLongitude());
    }
    return longi;
}

public String getLat(Location loc) {
    String lat = null;
    if (loc != null) {
        lat = Double.toString(loc.getLatitude());
    }
    return lat;
}

class SendDataAsynctask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    private String lati;
    private String longi;
    private String datetime;
    private String udid, city, country, address;
    private WakeLock wakelock;

    public SendDataAsynctask(String lati, String longi, String address,
            String datetime, String udid, String city, String country,
            WakeLock wakeLock) {
        this.lati = lati;
        this.longi = longi;
        this.address = address;
        this.datetime = datetime;
        this.udid = udid;
        this.city = city;
        this.country = country;
        this.wakelock = wakeLock;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return ServerConnection.sendData(lati, longi, address, datetime,
                udid, city, country);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        Log.v(TAG, "onPostExecute");
        manager.removeUpdates(myLocationListener);
        manager.removeGpsStatusListener(mGPSStatusListener);
        if (wakeLock.isHeld()) {
            wakelock.release();
        }
        if(isGPS) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Location from GPS");
            turnGPSOff();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location from GPS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Log.v(TAG, "Location from Network");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location from Network", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        stopSelf();
    }
}

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location argLocation) {
        //location = argLocation;
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }
}

class LocTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    String provider;

    public LocTimerTask(String provider) {
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    final Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.v(TAG, "Timer Task run" + i);
            location = manager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            if (location != null) {
                Log.v(TAG, "in timer task run in if location not null");
                if (location.getLatitude() != 0.0f
                        && location.getLongitude() != 0.0f) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "in timer task run location not null coordinates not 0");
                    isGPS = true;
                    onLocationReceived(location);
                    myLocTimer.cancel();
                    mTimerTask.cancel();
                    turnGPSOff();
                }
            } else {
                Log.v(TAG, "in timer task run in else location null");
                /*if (i == MAX_ATTEMPTS) {
                    turnGPSOff();
                    myLocTimer.cancel();
                    mTimerTask.cancel();
                    if (location == null) {
                        Log.v(TAG, "Location from GPS null");
                        manager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000L, 50.0f,
                                myLocationListener);
                        location = manager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            if (location.getLatitude() != 0.0f
                                    && location.getLongitude() != 0.0f) {
                                onLocationReceived(location);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    isGPS = false;
                }*/
            }
            i++;
        }
    };

    public void run() {
        mHandler.post(r);
    }
}

private GpsStatus.Listener mGPSStatusListener = new GpsStatus.Listener() {

    @Override
    public synchronized void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {
        switch (event) {
        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS:
            Log.v(TAG, "GPS SAtellitestatus");
            GpsStatus status = manager.getGpsStatus(null);
            mSattelites = 0;
            Iterable<GpsSatellite> list = status.getSatellites();
            for (GpsSatellite satellite : list) {
                if (satellite.usedInFix()) {
                    mSattelites++;
                }
            }
            break;

        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Got First Fix",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;

        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STARTED:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS Event Started",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;

        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STOPPED:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS Event Stopped",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
};

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (myLocTimer != null) {
        myLocTimer.cancel();
        myLocTimer.purge();
    }

    if (mTimerTask != null) {
        if (mTimerTask.r != null) {
            mTimerTask.mHandler.removeCallbacks(mTimerTask.r);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationReceived(Location mLoc) {
    String lat = getLat(mLoc);
    String lon = getLong(mLoc);
    if (NetworkConnection.isOnline(getApplicationContext())) {
        new SendDataAsynctask(lat, lon, "", time, udid, city, country,
                wakeLock).execute();
        Log.v(TAG, "net available");
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Network unavailable",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.v(TAG, "net unavailable");
    }
}

private void turnGPSOff(){
    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

    if(provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is enabled
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
        sendBroadcast(poke);
    }
}

private void turnGPSOn(){
    Log.v(TAG, "turnGPSON Called");
    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

    if(!provider.contains("gps")){ 
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider"); 
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
        sendBroadcast(poke);
        Log.v(TAG, "alarm request sent from turnGPSOn");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WHy wait?  Turn on both network and GPS at the same time.  Then in your timer go like this:

```
   attempts++;  //attempts is a variable at class scope
   location = manager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
   if(location == null && attempts == 5){
      location = manager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
      if(location == null){
           //They must have their radio off, you aren't going to get a location.  Handle this error

       }
   }
   if(location == null){
      return; //wait for next try
   }
   attempts = 0;  //clear for next run
   //process location
```

Comment: Sorry,my mistake. I edited my question. Actually, I meant to say no. of attempts for e.g. 5 attempts. As, it may take more time for GPS to get first fix. That's why, I used timer. Shall, I go for using alarm?

Comment: Ah, ok different question then.  No, a timer should be fine, just check and make sure its actually going off.  See edited answer in a minute.